# clean function causing .is_valid() method to return false when used in form django 1.9.8

Tags: django, validation, django-forms, python-3.5, django-login

In a django project i'm working on I wrote a function to validate the data from a login form. Now whenever I run the `is_valid()` method on a instance of the login form it returns false everytime. I've been trying to figure out what's causing this problem all day.

**forms.py**:

```
 from django import forms
 from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, password_validation
 from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
 from .functions import *
 from .models import *

 class login_form(forms.Form):
     username = forms.CharField(max_length=64, label='Username', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'username...', 'class':'login-field'}))
     password = forms.CharField(max_length=24, label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'password...', 'class':'login-field'}))

     def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
         username = self.cleaned_data.get('username', None)
         password = self.cleaned_data.get('password', None)
         user_obj = None
         self._errors['username'] = None  #clears default username error
         self._errors['password'] = None  #clears default password error

         if username is not None:
             try:
                 user_obj = User.objects.get(username=username) 

                 if password_validation.validate_password(password, user_obj) is None:
                     self._errors['password'] = 'Password is incorrect. Please try again.'

             except User.DoesNotExist:
                 self._errors['username'] = 'User does not exist. Please use valid credentials.'

         else:
             self._errors['username'] = 'Please type a valid username.'


         return super(login_form, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpRequest, JsonResponse, HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from datetime import datetime
from .models import *
from .forms import *
from .functions import *
from os import *
import shutil
import json


 def home(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
        form = login_form(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.data.get('username')
            password = form.data.get('password')
            authenticate_usr_obj = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if authenticate_usr_obj is not None:
                login(request, authenticate_usr_obj)
                return redirect(dashboard)

     else:
         form = login_form()


     try:
        logout_successful = request.session.get('logout_complete', False)
        request.session['logout_complete'] = False

     except:
         logout_successsful = False

     context = {
        'body_class': 'login',
        'login': form,
        'logout_successful': logout_successful
     }

     return render(request, 'development/index.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by reading throught Forms API docs I can see that in your example you did not clean data before you tried to get them in lines:

```
username = self.cleaned_data.get('username', None)
password = self.cleaned_data.get('password', None)
```

try to first use clean() to validate the data, like this:

```
cleaned_data = super(login_form, self).clean()
```

Then you can try to get them like this:

```
username = cleaned_data.get('username', None)
password = cleaned_data.get('password', None)
```

You can find more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#validating-fields-with-clean)

### Version 2:

Ok, so first of all what I found in Django docs regarding the django.contrib.auth.password_validation.validate_password():

> ### [Integrating validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/passwords/#integrating-validation)
>
> **validate_password(password, user=None, password_validators=None)**
>
> Validates a password. **If all validators find the password valid, returns *None***. If one or more validators reject the password, raises a ValidationError with all the error messages from the validators.
>
> The user object is optional: if it’s not provided, some validators may not be able to perform any validation and will accept any password.

So the line:

`if password_validation.validate_password(password, user_obj) is None:`

should be:

`if password_validation.validate_password(password, user_obj) is not None:`

Second of all:

> ### [Form.errors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors)
>
> ```
> >>>> f.errors
> {'sender': ['Enter a valid email address.'], 'subject': ['This field is required.']}`
> ```
>
> In this dictionary, the keys are the field names, and the values are **lists of Unicode strings representing the error messages**. The error messages are stored in lists because a field can have multiple error messages.

So based on that, I would change lines where you define your custom messages to look more something like this:

```
self.errors['password'] = [u'Password is incorrect. Please try again.']
```

And the one last thing to remember is that clean method must return the cleaned_data.

Final version of forms.py code could look something like that:

```
def clean(self):
    super(login_form,self).clean()
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username', None)
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password', None)

    if username is not None:
        try:
            user_obj = User.objects.get(username=username) 
            if password_validation.validate_password(password, user_obj) is not None:
                self.errors['password'] = [u'Password is incorrect. Please try again.']
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            self.errors['username'] = [u'User does not exist. Please use valid credentials.']
    else:
        self.errors['username'] = [u'Please type a valid username.']
    return self.cleaned_data
```

Hopefully it helps this time.

Comment: I tried doing that initially, it still returns false

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve by writing your own `clean()` method? Is it just about the custom error messages in your form? Because all you are trying to do(except the error messages of course) in your `clean()` method can be done with the default one(without overriding it) - in my opinion.

Comment: I not only wanted to override the default error messages, but I find the default errors not dynamic enough. I wanted to include some logic during the validation so I could give more specific error messages (I.E. if a another user shares the same email, user doesn't exist, filling out specific fields before others.). I was trying to create a validation method that's more dynamic than the default one.

Comment: @TechEmperor95 you may want to check out the updated answer and give it a try.

Comment: My only question is how would you clear the other errors. I cleared errors values for username and password so one would only appear at a time in a specific order.

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly, but I think that what you are asking can be done with `self.errors = {}`.

Answer (score 0):

Tested your code above and I've encountered error due to forms self._errors

```
`Nonetype` object is not iterable
```

And here is my suggestion

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class login_form(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(
        max_length=64, label='Username',
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'username...', 'class': 'login-field'}))
    password = forms.CharField(
        max_length=24, label='Password',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'password...', 'class': 'login-field'}))

def clean_username(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data.get('username', None)
    if not data:
        raise ValidationError('Please type a valid username.',
                              code='invalid')
    return data

def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
    try:
        user_obj = User.objects.get(username=username)
        if not user_obj.check_password(password):
            raise ValidationError(
                    'Password is incorrect. Please try again',
                    code='incorrect')

    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise ValidationError(
            'User does not exist. Please use valid credentials.',
            code='invalid')
    return super(login_form, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth import logout

from .forms import *


def home(request):
    logout_successful = True
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = login_form(request.POST)
        # print form.errors

        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.data.get('username')
            password = form.data.get('password')
            authenticate_usr_obj = authenticate(
                username=username, password=password)
            if authenticate_usr_obj:
                login(request, authenticate_usr_obj)
                # print 'ok'
    else:
        form = login_form()
    logout_successful = request.user.is_authenticated()
    return render(request, 'base.html', {
        'body_class': 'login',
        'login': form,
        'logout_successful': logout_successful
    })


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
```

I'm still a beginner so feel free to comment something

Comment: I tried it out and it stores the errors as nonfield errors. It's a nice try but not exactly what I'm going fo.

Comment: if you want to set the `Password is incorrect.` and `Please type a valid username` you can use your code on self.errors['<username/password>'] = [u'string here'] to set the errors as field errors